# what's the difference between "custom" and "practice"?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

For example:

> 1. As for what language to speak among family members in a certain situation there is the traditional practice to follow.
> 2. As for what language to speak among family members in a certain situation there is the traditional custom to follow.

For example:

> 3. This is the custom of Jingpo wedding: the bride must pass three barriers before she gets to the bridegroom's home.
> 4. This is the practice of Jingpo wedding: the bride must pass three barriers before she gets to the bridegroom's home.

Example 1 and 3 are what I read in an article(a Chinese-English translation).
Jingpo is a people of China.

I looked up in a dictionary and it seems that "custom" is something which is usual or traditional in a particular society or in particular circumstances, and that "practice" is just something people do regularly...

So I suppose, for my examples, they are both OK to use but "custom" is better?

Comment: A clear straightforward answer: [What is the difference between habit, custom, practice and convention?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/42746/11458)

Answer (score 1):

> *As for what language to speak among family members in a certain situation there is the traditional practice to follow.*
>   *As for what language to speak among family members in a certain situation there is the traditional custom to follow.*

I would say that 'traditional practice' and 'custom' are synonyms. Therefore the phrase in your second version, 'traditional custom' means 'traditional traditional practice'. It is therefore tautological.

I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

The semantic ranges of the terms overlap considerably, but *custom* carries more strongly the notion of tradition that is not easily changed.

If your first example refers to what happens today without an implied "*and that's how it's always been done*", use *practice*.

Your second example leans more strongly towards *custom*.

Answer (score 0):

*Custom* and *traditional practice* are very similar.  *Customary*, however, is often used simply to mean *usual practice(s)* and will allow you to express your ideas more idiomatically:

*As for what language to speak among family members in a certain situation, **it is customary to follow traditional practice***:

***The customary practice*** at a Jingpo wedding is for the bride to pass three barriers before she gets to the bridegroom's home.